# SSRS chart to show totals by hour

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following data:

```
+--------------------------+---------------+
|        Date Time         | Number of Hit |
+--------------------------+---------------+
| 2011-10-03 13:01:00 + 10 |             2 |
| 2011-10-03 13:05:00 + 10 |             3 |
| 2011-10-03 14:01:00 + 10 |             4 |
| 2011-10-03 14:04:00 + 10 |             5 |
+--------------------------+---------------+
```

I would like to create a Chart using Reporting Services that shows:

```
13 - 5
14 - 9
```

Basically I would like to show the number of hits by hour. Could someone show me how to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? What version of Reporting Services are you using? Where are you getting your data?

Comment: I'm stuck on creating a Chart using Reporting Services that show: 13 - 5 14 - 9. Do you you know how to do this or just trying to be smart?

Comment: Only trying to be smart in a way that would help...
From your original question, it's very hard to know what _specific_ problem you were having, therefore hard to help you: you will get different types of help if you say you are getting an error message versus you just need help writing a query. Even now, I don't know what 13 - 5 14 -9 means: is that time ranges?  
Also, the SSRS has changed quite a bit in the last few releases, so indicating version somewhere is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what other requirements you have, but probably easiest to group by hour in you SQL query:

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, myDateTimeColumn, 0)) AS TimeByHour,
   SUM(hitCount) as Hits
FROM
   WebRecordsTable
GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, myDateTimeColumn, 0))
```

Then create a chart in SSRS and drag the Hits field to the Values section.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Jamie F. Not quiet what i wanted but your solution gave me hint. i.e. I used datepart(hour,myDateTimeColum) then used group by.

Comment: Sure. Yes Datepart() will group by hour, regardless of date, while my original answer will group by hour and date.